# Run independent java program on android device

Tags: java, android, swing

I have an android phone that runs on ics. I have a desktop application written in java which runs on desktop system.
Can I run independent java program on it?

Thanks

Comment: Swing application? No, you cannot.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions. If you wrote this app, and therefore are asking this from a programming perspective, please explain the nature of this "desktop application" (e.g., what parts of Java SE does it use?).

Comment: I have a gwt application written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you can't run a java application written for desktop directly on Android. Android has a heavily modified java runtime environment.

But rewriting your application for Android shouldn't be too much of a pain, as you just have to convert your UI to **Android widgets**(called "[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)") and to adapt your code to **Android  [Activities]**(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).